# Unwind segue to the root in a different storyboard in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, segue

I'm working on an iOS app and I have two storyboards and some view controllers in the project like below.

Main.storyboard --- tab bar controller --- Navigation controller --- viewcontroller1 --- storyboard reference --- viewcontroller2

I have another view controller in the tab bar controller, but I just ignored that part for now.

What I want to accomplish here is when I press a button in viewcontroller2, the app takes back the user to viewcontroller1.

I add the ibaction to the button and tried the following codes, but both of them take the user back to viewcontroller1 with no navigation bar and tab bar.

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1 (_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@IBAction func unwindToVC1 (_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    
}
```

Since there is no navigation bar and tab bar when I back from VC2 to VC1, I think what I need to do now is to find a way to back to the root of the Main.storyboard, so I can see both of them appeared(maybe?).

So my question is how can I go back to the root of the storyboard (or in this case I want to see the nav bar and tab bar appeared) from a view controller in different storyboard.

Comment: The first one should work so something else is wrongly configured.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response, matt. You are right. 
I had two codes to hide the Navigation bar and tab bar in my viewcontroller2, so that causes the issue. So the solution to this problem was add navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
in the viewcontroller2 and reappear the navigation bar and tab bar in the viewcontroller1.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote in the reply to matt, but basically, I had codes to disappear the navigation bar and tab bar in my code and that causes this issue. Adding this line works.

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1 (_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```